# Prove that $\sum\limits_{i\leq n} a_n X_n$ converges almost surely iff $\sum\limits_{i\leq n}a_n^2$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $(X_n)$ is a sequence of independent random variables with $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $(a_n)$ a sequence of real numbers.

Prove that $\sum\limits_{i\leq n} a_i X_i$ converges almost surely if and only if $\sum\limits_{i\leq n}a_i^2$ converges.

I would really appreciate a hint for the direction where I assume that $\sum\limits_{i\leq n} a_n X_n$ converges almost surely. The other direction was easier for me; I proved it with Kolmogorov's three series theorem.
I tried to prove it indirectly by looking at the third series of Kolmogorov's three series theorem: $$\sum\limits_{i\leq n} Var(a_i X_i [\vert a_i X_i \vert \leq \varepsilon]) = ... = \sum\limits_{i\leq n} a_i 1_{[\vert a_i \vert \leq \varepsilon]}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you choose $\varepsilon=1$, then both directions would follow by Kolmogorov's 3 series theorem.